# Working with shared memory in PHP

Tags: php, ipc, shared-memory

Why does [`shmop_open()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shmop-open.php) not return the shared memory ID, likes it seems to imply that it does in the documentation?

> On success shmop_open() will return an id that you can use to access the shared memory segment you've created.

In this example, you can see that the returned ID is `4`, but the shared memory ID is actually `578322450`:

```
[*@* *]$ php -r 'var_dump(shmop_open(0, 'c', 0666, 1024));'
int(4)
[*@* *]$ ipcs

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00000000 578322450  *         666        1024       0
```

If this is intended, how do I retrieve the value that shows up on the `ipcs` command from PHP?

Comment: Well, the docs don't say what kind of an ID is returned, it does just say that it'll return *an ID that can be used...*. I would not have interpreted the docs as returning the ID you are looking for. I would also guess that the details are abstracted away, so I doubt it's possible to natively get the ID that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intended. It returns an id that you can use in PHP to access the shared memory block. It is a shmop resource as you can see here: http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php

To figure out which one it is, use your own key instead of 0. I wrote up a quick example:

```
<?php
echo "Opening shared memory!\n";

if($shm_id = shmop_open(0xdeadbeef, 'c', 0666, 1024)) {
   echo "Opened shared memory\n";
   echo "Wrote " . shmop_write($shm_id, "Testing", 0) . " bytes.\n";
   echo shmop_read($shm_id, 0, 7) . "\n";
   var_dump($shm_id);
   echo $shm_id . "\n";
   $line = `ipcs -m |grep deadbeef`;
   list($null, $shmid, $null) = explode(' ', $line);
   echo "shmid is: " . $shmid . "\n";
}
?>
```

Output:

> Opening shared memory! 
>   Opened shared memory Wrote 7 bytes. 
>   Testing
>   int(4) 
>   4
>   shmid is: 1533149226

And as you can see, it is easy to find:

> ```
> [nedwidek@yule ~]$ ipcs -m |grep deadbeef
> 0xdeadbeef 1533149226 nedwidek   666        1024       0
> ```

Just an update on what I've pursued:

From php-src/ext/shmop/shmop.c (https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/shmop/shmop.c)

```
rsid = zend_list_insert(shmop, shm_type TSRMLS_CC);
RETURN_LONG(rsid);
```

Two things here.... Validates that you get a resource id back and the shmop struct is persisted. This means that shmod->shmid can be obtained.

I've also subscribed to the internals mailing list. I'll be posting a query on why they don't allow you to get the shmid, if a function were introduced to get it (or maybe the shmop details as a hash array) would they merge a patch for this.

Let me know what your interest level is in any of this (collaborate on a patch, receive any patch I come up with, wait for PHP to officially integrate (if ever), or none). If you're not interested at all, I'll stop updating my answer. -- Regards Erik.

Comment: I added one way to get the shmid in PHP. I don't believe there is a way to get it with a pure PHP implementation (other than creating an extension). I'd love to be proved wrong.

Comment: +1 for the good answer.  Unfortunately, I need to use 0 though.  I'm recreating a legacy C program, and it uses `IPC_PRIVATE` as the key.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm actually rather curious on why the PHP devs never saw it fit to expose the shmid into PHP. I get the whole resource abstraction that they are doing, but to not give you a way to see the underlying OS resource identifiers..... Might be a good question for the dev list.

Comment: If you're at all interested in patching your version of PHP, I've committed a version that introduces shmop_sys_shmid(). Pass it your PHP shmop ID and you get the OS shmid. https://github.com/nedwidek/php-src/commit/832e77fce15de926b562b6dcc28d1864bb7c348b

Comment: Good work.  I'm interested, but I'm unfortunately not in a position to patch PHP on my target machines.  If you haven't already, I would suggest that you submit this patch, though.